# MDriven Turnkey issues with new device

Tags: modeling, mdriven

I'm having these weird issues with TK ever since I started using a new windows 10 laptop.

1. The TK azurewebsite won't load in chrome (or any other browser for that matter)
2. When checking the server status in CloudForm inside the designer I get this error: "System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state"
3. When downloading the model picked as work site it stated "error in server endpoint"

The application has no errors and evolves successully on other devices, so there must be a vital part I've missed in the switch of computers.

What could these problems be caused by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a glitch in the "Pick as Work site" option.
What should happen is that the pwd and server address should be populated in the MDriven Server tab.  It is probably not pointing on the correct server or has the correct pwd when you get this error.

If you have more than one turnkey site - try switching between the two and click "Pick as work site". If you only have 1 site - create another one so that you can switch.

Please report back to support at capableobjects.com if you find any consistent behavior that can explain the bug.

Comment: I see, thanks, got it to work now somehow, hopefully it won't happen again.

Comment: Nevermind, it keeps happening, will report to support@capableObjects.com regarding the issue.